# Plotting a adjacency matrix using pure R

Tags: r, matrix, graph

What I want to do is following:

Let's say I have a 3X2 matrix that holds the coordinates of a coordinate system

```
         1   2
         5   3
         4   2
```

And let's say that I have an adjacency matrix that has rows and columns as the previous matrix has rows so something like this:

```
         2 1 0
         1 0 1
         0 1 0
```

Now what I want to do is to plot this adjacency matrix in the given coordinate system , it should look similar to this:

[image: Resulting graph]

For doing that I'm only allowed to use base R , so no igraph or network or any other package that is not pre-loaded
when you start R.

*****EDIT*****

With the help from @lukeA I managed to do this:

> plot(coordinates)
>
> idx <- which(adjacency>0, arr.ind = T)
>
> number = ncol(adjacency) * nrow(adjacency)
>
> for(i in 1:number)

{
arrows(coordinates[idx[i,1],1], coordinates[idx[i,1],2], coordinates[idx[i,2],1], coordinates[idx[i,2],2])
 }

With this result:

[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4H3.jpg)

Comment: With regards to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837240/visualizing-a-graph-in-the-coordinate-system-given-by-x#comment74711394_43837240)  - where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well basicaly what ever I do I can't draw the network without using other packages , I'm doing it fine with igraph but with basic graphics no.

Comment: Please add the basic graphics code that you tried to your post. I mean you can plot the vertices using `plot(my3x2matrix)`. You can get the information for the edges by using for example `which(adjmatrix>0, arr.ind = T)` in connection with the coordinates in `my3x2matrix`. The line widths is in `adjmatrix[adjmatrix>0]`. And you can use `arrows` to draw (straight) arrows. I dunno about curved ones though (for example self loops).

Comment: What do you mean, "I'm only allowed to use base R"? WHO is forbidding you to build upon the hard work of smart people?

Comment: I will try now your sugestion , if I manage I will post the answer and give you credit ,  thanks for helping me :)

Comment: @celeb1994 I thought more of `plot(coordinates);idx <- which(adjacency>0, arr.ind = T);arrows(coordinates[idx[3,1],1], coordinates[idx[3,1],2], coordinates[idx[3,2],1], coordinates[idx[3,2],2])`. This plots the third edge. You'll have to loop over all edges indicated in idx.